# Saving html5 audio to Node.js express server

Tags: javascript, node.js, html, express

```html
<audio controls="" autoplay="" src="blob:http://localhost:8000/e550aa2b-8d69-4e97-9e60-a821ea5d61e4"></audio>
```

How can I saving this blob to my database then retrieve it another times?

Is `base64` the best pratice?

Or how can I download the audio to file to my server folder?

Comment: but the string is too long,will it cause database query latency?

Comment: Look like    
`URL.createObjectURL()` only return a blob url,is it possible to save this to database?